# Django Nginx is not serving wagtail admin css/js files

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I set up my django wagtail on a ubuntu server with a domain using NGINX and Gunicorn. My CSS and JS files located in the static folder in my directory are being served correctly, but I can't figure out why the Wagtail Admin CSS/JS files are not being served. I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that the Wagtail admin files are not located in my static folder with my CSS/JS files. 
I ran CollectStatic and set Debug=False.

Google chrome is reporting a 404 files not found on the admin CSS/JS

**Part of NGINX File**

```
server {
        listen 443 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 default_server;

        root /home/projects/stemletics/stemletics/mysite/mysite;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/projects/stemletics/stemletics/mysite/mysite;
        }
        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/projects/stemletics/stemletics/mysite/mysite.sock;
        }
```

**Relevant part of Base.py**

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


# Wagtail settings

WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = "mysite"

# Base URL to use when referring to full URLs within the Wagtail admin backend -
# e.g. in notification emails. Don't include '/admin' or a trailing slash
BASE_URL = 'http://example.com'
```

**Production.py**

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

import os
SECRET_KEY = os.environ["DJANGO_SECRET_KEY_STEMLETICS"]

try:
    from .local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

**Static folder path**

```
root@django-manaland:/# cd home/projects/stemletics/stemletics/mysite/mysite/static/
root@django-manaland:/home/projects/stemletics/stemletics/mysite/mysite/static# lsbrand  css  fonts  img  js  scss
```

Comment: You are configuring it incorrectly, I don't think your static directory is `/home/projects/stemletics/stemletics/mysite/mysite`. Please post the relevant portions from your `settings.py`.

Comment: Added requested information to post

Comment: Your `location /static/` should point to the static directory, i.e. `/my/project/dir/static`. How your own CSS/JS files are being served is a mystery but I think it is because you hand coded the static URLs in your HTML (and they point to the wrong location too).

Comment: Lol my Nginx file was so messed up, I completely understand now though. Both my root and static location in my Nginx file was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your nginx conf file, you'll need to point to the directory you want to serve static assets from. At first glance, what you have looks correct (although I'm not 100% certain whether or not you need the trailing slash in the example below; I always leave in the trailing slash just in case)

```
# your nginx site.conf file

# Site static media
location /static/ {
  # Use `pwd` to get this path, wherever your static assets are collected into
  alias /home/user/www/your_website/static_collected/; 
}
```

To get that path (from above), ssh into your server, `cd` into your directory where Django's `collectstatic` function merges your files, then run `pwd`. It'll return a path, and make sure you end it with a trailing slash (the slash has always worked for me)